# How to synchronize a GitHub repository and multiple Gists

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, github, gist

I am developing a pretty large JavaScript library ([Formula.js](http://stoic.com/formula/)) of functions (450+). Most of them are pretty independent from each other and totally self-contained, or make use of well-known third-party libraries (Moment.js for example). In order to support discussions and manage contributions at the function level rather than at the library level, I created one [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) per function (*Cf.* [CONVERT](https://gist.github.com/4503203) Gist), and one [repository](https://github.com/sutoiku/formula.js) for the entire library. This makes it easy to include the code of a function in the function's documentation (Cf. [CONVERT](http://stoic.com/formula/function.html?name=CONVERT) documentation).

**My question is:** how do I keep the master repository synchronized with the Gists?

**The solution should:**

- allow changes to be made from the master repository and from the individual Gists
- automate the inclusion of copyright headers on the individual Gists
- automate the inclusion of comments related to third-party libraries on the individual Gists

**Additional thoughts:**

I could not find many examples of projects being managed that way. I'm also rather unexperienced with Git. Therefore, the workflow I'm suggesting might be totally flawed, or introduce unwanted complexity. Any thoughts on possible best practices for keeping things under control are much welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as each gist is in fact a git repository, you could use the git submodule feature to include them all in your primary GitHub repository.

Have a look at this page from the book, http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules , it even has a section on so-called *Superprojects*.

Answer (score 3):

And you could use [Github.js](https://github.com/michael/github) to add copyright headers and library-related comments.